# Proper way to add `test/resources` directory to classpath on test phase

Tags: grails

Using Grails 2.2.3

I'm going to keep my test resources in test/resources directory. Want to expand test classpath with it. In BuildConfig.groovy I've added this line:

```
grailsSettings.testDependencies.add new File("${basedir}/test/resources")
```

After that `grails test-app unit:` fails with:

```
_GrailsClasspath_groovy: 17: unable to resolve class     org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler
 @ line 17, column 1.
```

Exception gone if I'm commenting out this line.

For sure **this code worked** in Grails 1.3.2

**UPDATE 1**

Tried to upgrade to Grails 2.2.4. Same problem

**UPDATE 2**

Here's full stacktrace

```
| Error Error executing script TestApp: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsProjectCompiler (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsProjectCompiler
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:36)
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at TestApp.run(TestApp.groovy:24)
at TestApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler
... 17 more
| Error Error executing script TestApp: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsProjectCompiler
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all build path options in `grails.util.BuildSettings` class.
I don't found any special folder for test resources.
Try to create `/test/resources` folder. It should be the same.